# How to run a command only if a specific file has a certain size

Tags: linux, find

How can I execute a command only if a certain file exceeds a defined size? Both should at the end run as a oneliner in crontab.

Pseudocode:

```
* * * * * find /cache/myfile.csv -size +5G && echo "file is > 5GB"
```

Comment: If your goal is to trigger this when the file exceeds that size, but the file is only infrequently written to, you may want to use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to trigger the check instead of running it every minute.

Comment: I don't look closely at the answers. Just FYI, beware of sparse files reported wrongly. These are not easy to handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the file size as a precondition you can [use `stat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/746051/100397) or `find`:

```
[ -n "$(find /cache/myfile.csv -prune -size +5G 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo "file is > 5GB"
```

Or if the target command (`echo`, here) is short, put it into the `exec` part of `find

```
find /cache/myfile.csv -prune -size +5G -exec echo "file is > 5GB" \;
```

The `-prune` is in case `myfile.csv` might be a file of type directory, to prevent `find` from descending into it.

Answer (score 11):

If you have GNU `stat`, you can use its `--printf` option to get its size.

e.g.

```
size=$(stat --printf '%s' /cache/myfile.csv)
if [ "$size" -gt 5368709120 ] ; then  # 5 GiB = 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
  echo "file is > 5GB"
fi
```

See `man stat` for details.

---

BSD's `stat` (e.g. on FreeBSD and on Mac) has a similar formatting option, `-f`:

```
size=$(stat -f '%z' /cache/myfile.csv)
```

---

Alternatively, you could use perl's built-in `stat` function, or its `-s` file test operator (which is similar to bash's `-s` file test but it returns the file's size rather than just true if it exists and is non-empty).
perl's stat function returns a 13-element list (array) of metadata about a file containing the following data (copied from `perldoc -f stat`):

```
[...] Not all fields are supported on all filesystem types. Here are
the meanings of the fields: 

  0 dev      device number of filesystem
  1 ino      inode number
  2 mode     file mode  (type and permissions)
  3 nlink    number of (hard) links to the file 
  4 uid      numeric user ID of file's owner
  5 gid      numeric group ID of file's owner
  6 rdev     the device identifier (special files only) 
  7 size     total size of file, in bytes
  8 atime    last access time in seconds since the epoch
  9 mtime    last modify time in seconds since the epoch
 10 ctime    inode change time in seconds since the epoch (*)
 11 blksize  preferred I/O size in bytes for interacting with the
             file (may vary from file to file)
 12 blocks   actual number of system-specific blocks allocated
             on disk (often, but not always, 512 bytes each) 

(The epoch was at 00:00 January 1, 1970 GMT.)
```

Field 7 is the one we need.

To return the file's size (for later use in a shell command or script) using `stat`:

```
# stat
perl -e 'print scalar((stat(shift))[7])' /cache/myfile.csv

# -s
perl -e 'print -s shift' /cache/myfile.csv
```

Or to do it all in perl:

```
# stat
perl -e 'print "File is > 5 GiB\n" if (stat(shift))[7] > 5*1024*1024*1024' /cache/myfile.csv

# -s
perl -e 'print "File is > 5 GiB\n" if -s shift > 5*1024*1024*1024' /cache/myfile.csv
```

See `perldoc -f stat` and `perldoc -f -X` (as well as `help test` in bash).

BTW, perl's `shift` function removes the first element of an array (by default `@ARGV`, the array of command line args, if not specified) and returns its value.  It's often used in a loop to process all elements of an array, but here we're only interested in the first arg (the filename).  See `perldoc -f shift` for details, including notes on lexical scope and use in a subroutine.

Comment: The OP question is `if find-command was successful`

Comment: yes, but the OP is asking the wrong question, using the wrong tool for the job.  If you want to measure your door's height or width, you use a tape-measure or a ruler, not a bucket or a hammer.  Similarly, if you want to know the size of a file, you use `stat`, not `find` (and not `ls` either).  Part of our job when answering a question is to tell people when they're using the wrong tool or asking the wrong question, to find the underlying task hidden beneath the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @cas If you want to test the size of a file _portably_, then `find` is the correct tool (albeit not with "+5G" as the argument to `-size`).

Comment: Portability was never part of the question.  It's tagged `linux`, and linux means GNU tools on everything but tiny distros with only busybox available (and even busybox stat has a `-c` formatting option with `%s` meaning size in bytes just like GNU stat).   More to the point, `find` is the wrong tool for getting metadata about a file such as the file's size. That's `stat`'s job, it's what it's for.   If stat didn't have formatting options, the next best option is not find, it's perl with its built-in `stat()` function because that's a trivial one-liner compared to a dozen or so lines in C.

Comment: e.g. `perl -e '$size = (stat(shift))[7]; print $size' /cache/myfile.csv`

Comment: or, even shorter, `perl -e 'print scalar((stat(shift))[7])' /cache/myfile.csv`

Comment: OP asked for a one-liner for use in crontab. How can this be used in the way OP asked?

Comment: they already know how to use crontab, they didn't know how to test the file size.

Comment: the perl version can be even shorter - perl's `-s` file test returns the size of the file (bash's `-s` test only returns true if the file exist and is not empty, false otherwise), so extracting the size from the list returned by `stat()` isn't necessary.  e.g. `perl -e 'print -s shift' filename` to output the size for use in shell, or do it all in perl with `print "File is > 5GB\n" if -s shift > 5*1024*1024*1024' filename`.   See `perldoc -f -X` for docs on perl's file tests (and `help test` in bash for bash's file tests).

Answer (score 4):

If you need to treat files in a shell, both version only execute shell's command only if all conditions are met: is a file, is named `myfile.csv` and is > 5G:

```
find /cache -name 'myfile.csv' -type f -size +5G -exec bash -c '
    echo "$1 is > 5GB"
' bash {} \;
```

or

```
find /cache -name 'myfile.csv' -type f -size +5G -exec bash -c '
    for file; do echo "$file is > 5GB"; done
' bash {} +
```

Comment: I don't want to iterate the files. I just want to use this as a precondition before starting another process. I could as well write `find .... +5G && start.sh`. So, only start the 2nd command if the find command found the file which was above a certain size.

Comment: So use the first version, and replace `echo` by `start.sh`

Comment: if you don't want to iterate over files, then don't use find.  You could use `stat` instead.

Comment: @membersound If `/cache/myfile` isn't a directory, neither command in the answer will do much iterating.  Using `find` is about the only portable way of conditionally executing a command based on the size of a file.

Comment: @Kusalananda, for readable files, `wc -c` can get the size of a file portably (though not always as efficiently in the `wc` implementations that don't do optimisations when the  size of the file can be obtained other than by reading it).

Answer (score 2):

Note that some shells have the feature built-in.

```
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
* * * * * if (-Z /cache/myfile.csv > 5*1024*1024*1024) echo 'file is > 5GiB'
```

Or with `zsh`, here using glob qualifiers and an anonymous functions, though zsh also has a `stat`  builtin that predates both GNU and BSD `stat`:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
* * * * * (){ if (($#)) echo 'file is > 5GiB'; } /cache/myfile.csv(NLG+5)
```

(note that like for `find -size +5G`, we're talking of gibibytes (1GiB = 1,073,741,824 bytes) here, not gigabytes (1GB = 1,000,000,000 bytes))

For symlinks, `tcsh` will get the size of the file it eventually resolved to while `zsh`'s `LG+5` qualifier like `find`'s `-size` will check the size of symlink itself. Change to `-LG+5` to check the size after symlink resolution. `zsh`'s `stat` builtin gives you information after symlink resolution by default, `-L` to change that. In GNU and BSD `stat`, that's reversed. Same with `find` where `-L` tells it to follow symlinks.

For more ways to get the size of a file, see [How can I get the size of a file in a bash script?](/a/321502)